# How to Add Comma seperated Object types into NgFor loop?

Tags: json, angular, ngfor

I want to bind the currency codes and Values seperatly

```
"rates": {
        "USD": 1,
        "AED": 3.672057,
        "ARS": 56.01249,
        "AUD": 1.46368,
        "BGN": 1.77167,
        "BRL": 4.087588,
        "BSD": 1,
        "CAD": 1.320503,
        "CHF": 0.987394,
        "CLP": 716.341326,
        "CNY": 7.13045,
        "COP": 3416.761905,
        "CZK": 23.407844,
        "DKK": 6.757576,
        "DOP": 51.214847,
        "EGP": 16.42298,
        "EUR": 0.906246,
        "FJD": 2.190098,
        "GBP": 0.812305,
        "GTQ": 7.682227,
        "HKD": 7.838661,
        "HRK": 6.706097,
        "HUF": 298.791592,
        "IDR": 14146.297846,
        "ILS": 3.517842,
        "INR": 71.751368,
        "ISK": 126.170061,
        "JPY": 106.936393,
        "KRW": 1194.541725,
        "KZT": 387.848649,
        "MXN": 19.613284,
        "MYR": 4.184189,
        "NOK": 8.99096,
        "NZD": 1.561619,
        "PAB": 1,
        "PEN": 3.352305,
        "PHP": 51.899054,
        "PKR": 156.32244,
        "PLN": 3.930302,
        "PYG": 6522.909091,
        "RON": 4.285713,
        "RUB": 65.941596,
        "SAR": 3.75059,
        "SEK": 9.657741,
        "SGD": 1.382595,
        "THB": 30.646268,
        "TRY": 5.701489,
        "TWD": 31.23947,
        "UAH": 24.982101,
        "UYU": 36.570846,
        "VND": 23112.280702,
        "ZAR": 14.803694
    }
```

this is on my view :

```
 <a class="dropdown-item w-r" *ngFor="let cur of currencies?.rates" (click)="onCurrency(cur)" >{{cur}}</a>
```

error :

> Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type
>   'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: <a class="dropdown-item w-r" *ngFor="let cur of currencies?.rates" (click)="onCurrency(cur)" >{{cur}}</a>

this is on my view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try to use **keyvalue** pipe:

```
<a class="dropdown-item w-r" *ngFor="let cur of currencies?.rates | keyvalue" (click)="onCurrency(cur)" ><br>{{cur.key}}:{{cur.value}}</a>
```

[**StackBlitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k64cma)

Comment: This is Exactly i wanted. Simple and best solution, thanks

Comment: @RimoDeRodrego using pipe is a bad practice

Comment: @Sajeetharan No it’s not..? Pipes are often the recommended way to do things.

Comment: @Sajeetharan-MSFT, why would the `keyvalue` pipe be bad practice? I don't think angular team would provide this pipe if you shouldn't use it...

Comment: in fact, it will help you to achieve things you wanted when it comes to performance using a pipe with ngFor is certainly a bad practice.

Comment: @Sajeetharan-MSFT Well explain to me, why angular provides the `keyvalue` pipe if we shouldn't use it? Can you give a reference where it says we shouldn't use the `keyvalue` pipe? Angular team talks about not creating a orderBy or filter pipe and they are **not** providing a pipe for that.

Comment: hey folks, in this case, its absolutely right using a keyvalue pipe, I just gave a heads up not to use in other places. OP seems very new user on Angular

Comment: @Sajeetharan-MSFT I agree that pure pipes should be avoided when possible, but the `keyvalue` pipe should be ok, as it's built in. I have a feeling you didn't know the pipe existed.

Comment: if you think so let it be. I have answered many questions earlier using keyvalue pipe, just that i did not use in my answer :) cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

To use ngFor, you need to conver your Object to an array of Object. Do it as follows on the .TS

```js
let curr = {
  "rates": {
    "USD": 1,
    "AED": 3.672057,
    "ARS": 56.01249,
    "AUD": 1.46368,
    "BGN": 1.77167,
    "BRL": 4.087588,
    "BSD": 1,
    "CAD": 1.320503,
    "CHF": 0.987394,
    "CLP": 716.341326,
    "CNY": 7.13045,
    "COP": 3416.761905,
    "CZK": 23.407844,
    "DKK": 6.757576,
    "DOP": 51.214847,
    "EGP": 16.42298,
    "EUR": 0.906246,
    "FJD": 2.190098,
    "GBP": 0.812305,
    "GTQ": 7.682227,
    "HKD": 7.838661,
    "HRK": 6.706097,
    "HUF": 298.791592,
    "IDR": 14146.297846,
    "ILS": 3.517842,
    "INR": 71.751368,
    "ISK": 126.170061,
    "JPY": 106.936393,
    "KRW": 1194.541725,
    "KZT": 387.848649,
    "MXN": 19.613284,
    "MYR": 4.184189,
    "NOK": 8.99096,
    "NZD": 1.561619,
    "PAB": 1,
    "PEN": 3.352305,
    "PHP": 51.899054,
    "PKR": 156.32244,
    "PLN": 3.930302,
    "PYG": 6522.909091,
    "RON": 4.285713,
    "RUB": 65.941596,
    "SAR": 3.75059,
    "SEK": 9.657741,
    "SGD": 1.382595,
    "THB": 30.646268,
    "TRY": 5.701489,
    "TWD": 31.23947,
    "UAH": 24.982101,
    "UYU": 36.570846,
    "VND": 23112.280702,
    "ZAR": 14.803694
  }
};

const mapped = Object.keys(curr.rates).map(key => ({type: key, value: curr.rates[key]}));

console.log(mapped);
```

Answer (score 0):

What I have understand from you is that you are trying to show all data in json by iterating with ngFor
I suggest you to parse that json in code behind and iterate in "result" object
like :

1. parse your json in your code behind
2. create getter for result attribute keys

   get Resultkeys(){ return Object.keys(result); }
3. create function that gets value of a given key

   getResultKeyValue(key){ return result[key]; }
4. iterate in ResultKeys in your html code usign ngFor
5. display {{getResultKeyValue(key)}}

Answer (score 0):

Use Object.entries

*Object.entries(obj) – returns an array of [key, value] pairs.*

```js
var cur = { "USD": 1, "AED": 3.672057, "ARS": 56.01249, "AUD": 1.46368, "BGN": 1.77167, "BRL": 4.087588, "BSD": 1, "CAD": 1.320503, "CHF": 0.987394, "CLP": 716.341326, "CNY": 7.13045, "COP": 3416.761905, "CZK": 23.407844, "DKK": 6.757576, "DOP": 51.214847, "EGP": 16.42298, "EUR": 0.906246, "FJD": 2.190098, "GBP": 0.812305, "GTQ": 7.682227, "HKD": 7.838661, "HRK": 6.706097, "HUF": 298.791592, "IDR": 14146.297846, "ILS": 3.517842, "INR": 71.751368, "ISK": 126.170061, "JPY": 106.936393, "KRW": 1194.541725, "KZT": 387.848649, "MXN": 19.613284, "MYR": 4.184189, "NOK": 8.99096, "NZD": 1.561619, "PAB": 1, "PEN": 3.352305, "PHP": 51.899054, "PKR": 156.32244, "PLN": 3.930302, "PYG": 6522.909091, "RON": 4.285713, "RUB": 65.941596, "SAR": 3.75059, "SEK": 9.657741, "SGD": 1.382595, "THB": 30.646268, "TRY": 5.701489, "TWD": 31.23947, "UAH": 24.982101, "UYU": 36.570846, "VND": 23112.280702, "ZAR": 14.803694 }

Object.entries(cur).forEach(obj => console.log(`${obj[0]} ${obj[1]}`));
```